# Map View Not Showing All Annotations

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

I have a Parse class that has all of the info I need for each annotation on my map view. I am running a Parse query to retrieve the data. I'm adding the data to arrays because I am using the arrays for some other functionality. The problem I'm having is that only five of the annotations are showing up on my map even though the array of annotations has the number of annotations I'm expecting (98). What am I doing wrong?

getMarkets method (this is called in viewDidLoad)

```
- (void)getMarkets {
    self.lat = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.lon = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.title1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.subtitle1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.phoneNumbers = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.websites = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    marketLocations = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Markets"];
    [query setLimit:1000];
    [query orderByAscending:@"Name"];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            for (NSDictionary *objectDictionary in objects) {
                [self.title1 addObject:[objectDictionary objectForKey:@"CompanyName"]];
                [self.subtitle1 addObject:[objectDictionary objectForKey:@"MarketAddress"]];
                [self.phoneNumbers addObject:[objectDictionary objectForKey:@"MarketPhone"]];
                [self.websites addObject:[objectDictionary objectForKey:@"Website"]];
                [self.lat addObject:[objectDictionary objectForKey:@"Latitude"]];
                [self.lon addObject:[objectDictionary objectForKey:@"Longitude"]];

                marketAnnotation = [[FarmMarketAnnotation alloc]init];
                location.latitude = [[objectDictionary objectForKey:@"Latitude"]floatValue];
                location.longitude = [[objectDictionary objectForKey:@"Longitude"]floatValue];
                marketAnnotation.coordinate = location;
                marketAnnotation.title = [objectDictionary objectForKey:@"CompanyName"];
                marketAnnotation.subtitle = [objectDictionary objectForKey:@"MarketAddress"];
                marketAnnotation.phoneNumber = [objectDictionary objectForKey:@"MarketPhone"];
                marketAnnotation.website = [objectDictionary objectForKey:@"Website"];
                [marketLocations addObject:marketAnnotation];
            }

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {
                NSLog(@"Annotations Count: %lu", (unsigned long)marketLocations.count);
                [worldView addAnnotations:marketLocations];
            });
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: Are only 5 annotations added to the mapView or do you just see 5 annotations? Maybe their coordinates are not in the area you show on the map.

Comment: Only 5 are being added

Comment: And you can NSLog all 98 locations ?

Comment: Yes, and I get all 98 results I expect.

Comment: I just did another NSLog and while I am getting the number expected, all but the 5 annotations actually showing up have a longitude of 0.000000.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. For all but those 5 annotations, there was a new line character in front of the longitude in my database.